# How to extract a given string out of another?

Tags: vbscript

I would like to extract a given string out of another one.

The sample strings shall be:

V_DDRF_**2J**_WTF

V_ASDF_**8J**_TLDR

V_LULZ_1337_**3J**

(Hint: The letter after the integer is ALWAYS a J.)

Now I only want to extract the integer of the **bold** part of the string. How do I achieve that?
`xJ` will only appear in the middle or the end of the string.

Comment: Not possible given the current information.  There is no discernible pattern.

Comment: Also, please demonstrate [what you have tried so far](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: Well I haven't tried THAT much as I can't find a solution with my skills. For the first two ones I just did `LEFT()` and `MID()`, but then the third one came... Maybe there is a solution with regular expressions? As one may look for `anything_?J`, but never really tried regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [RegExp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee236360%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) searching for "*", a (sequence of) number(s), and an optional "*" - as in:

```
Option Explicit

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function

Dim aTests : aTests = Array( _
     "V_DDRF_2J_WTF" , "_2J_" _
   , "V_ASDF_8J_TLDR", "_8J_" _
   , "V_LULZ_1337_3J", "_3J"  _
)
Dim r : Set r = New RegExp
'r.Pattern = "_\d+J(?:_|$)"
r.Pattern = "_\d+J_?"
Dim i, s
For i = 0 To UBound(aTests) Step 2
    s = r.Execute(aTests(i + 0))(0).Value
    WScript.Echo   qq(aTests(i + 0)) _
                 , qq(s) _
                 , CStr(aTests(i + 1) = s)

Next
```

output:

```
cscript 28561918.vbs
"V_DDRF_2J_WTF" "_2J_" True
"V_ASDF_8J_TLDR" "_8J_" True
"V_LULZ_1337_3J" "_3J" True
```

You may have to tinker with the pattern, depending on your input data; code to deal with non-matches should be added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and use this pattern `\d+J` or `\d+\w`

You can test patterns [here](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: The first one did it. The second one also highlights preceding numbers (e.g. `1337_3J´). And thanks for that pattern testern, as I may get into regexp now. :)